# Wordpress echoing a certain custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I am trying to echo a specific custom field named 'Price'.

I have tried

```
 <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true); ?>
```

How can i echo the Price field?

Comment: how are you saving your post meta? Are you sure that the post meta is called 'Price'? So if you: `echo print_r(get_post_meta($post->ID));` you do see "Price" is in that meta array correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first have to get information about current post of Wordpress in a variable. For this you can use:

```
global $post;
```

This will get all post information in variable **$post**.

Than you can call your function and it should work:

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true);
```

But **Price** should be a meta property for that post.

Answer (score 1):

Try echoing the post meta with this:

```
global $post;    
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Price', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be about, getting **post ID**.

```
echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'Price', true);
```

Also, you should use this inside **loop**.